# TypeScript type for all JS objects that can be passed to Object.keys(o)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to determine what the parameter type is for `Object.keys()`, here is the official declaration (lib.es6.d.ts):

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
    new(value?: any): Object;
    (): any;
    (value: any): any;

    ...

    /**
      * Returns the names of the enumerable properties and methods of an object.
      * @param o Object that contains the properties and methods. This can be an object that you created or an existing Document Object Model (DOM) object.
      */
    keys(o: any): string[];
}
```

So I have a function like so:

```
 v.registerMap = function (o: NotSureWhatTypeToUse): Promise<Array<any>> {

        let keys: Array<string>;

        try {
          keys = Object.keys(o);  // perhaps this will never throw
        }
        catch (err) {
          _suman.log.error('Could not call Object.keys(o), where o is:', util.inspect(o));
          throw err;
        }

        return Promise.all(keys.map(function (k) {

          try {
            return valuesMap[k] = o.get(k)
          }
          catch (err) {
            return valuesMap[k] = o[k];
          }

        }));
      };
```

as you can see above, I am trying to handle the case where the original parameter is a Map or a plain object.

The async library uses `Dictionary<{}>` for its TypeScript type for a similar type of parameter. Is that the one I am looking for?

In the async library, this type looks like:

```
export interface Dictionary<T> { [key: string]: T; }
```

Perhaps the one I am looking for.

Comment: Do you get an error from the code above, or does it not work properly in some way? What is `valuesMap`? `Object.keys` will throw an error for `null` or `undefined`, but usually you'll just get an empty array for non-object values

Comment: yeah one of the trickiest things in JS, is knowing when foreign code will throw an error or not. I can't tell if Object.keys() will ever throw.

Comment: But what the question is asking, is what type I should limit the function to, and I think `type t = {}` works.

Comment: I am going to have to ask a different question on SO, to try to get an answer to the question that I gave in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do, is just to limit the input to plain objects, something like this:

```
type PlainObj = {}

v.registerMap = function (o: PlainObj): Promise<Array<any>> {...};
```

one thing I am confused about, however, is how generics work in the async library. The async lib use Dictionary, like so:

```
export interface Dictionary<T> { [key: string]: T; }
```

I don't know how `Dictionary<any>` is different from `PlainObj`.